# Getting a book on C and C++ for Xcode

Tags: c++, c, xcode, cocoa-touch, xcode5

I live in Canada, and I have been learning to make apps for iOS in Xcode 5 for a month now, off scraps from the internet. I was wondering if anyone could recommend and easy to learn book for Xcode
(Like C and C++ (I know is C++ is hard) that is available in Canada.

Comment: You want a book about C, C++, Objective-C, Xcode or iOS?

Comment: [Definitive C++ Book List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Cocoa and Objective-C: Up and Running**

That's a good book I've read.

It's available in Canada among other countries.